# Why Magento re-saves existing customer addresses during checkout?

Tags: checkout, customer, address

During the checkout process even if customer selects existing address form the drop-down the `customer_address` entity is being re-saved. Any idea what for?

**Update:**

It starts at `Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage::saveOrder` where the following code is executed:

```
$service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_quote', $this->getQuote());
$service->submitAll();
```

This `submitAll` calls `Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote::submitOrder` which executes the following:

```
$transaction->save();
```

This method loops through all objects of the quote(?) and saves them.

**Update:**

The most disgusting thing is that they are doing it for all addresses customer has. So if your visitor get 10 addresses saved in the address book all of them will be re-saved during checkout. Don't wonder why it is the most resource consuming part of Magento.

Comment: In the `customer_address_entity` or in the quote?

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean. The `customer_address` entity is being saved during placing the order. No connection to quote.

Comment: Can you provide the code that does this? It would save me the trouble of searching

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: @Tim I guess the answer cause they did not think it through would be an acceptable answer ;) My guess is that they did'nt want to check if the address exists so it would be easier/lazier to save everything. Only a guess though

Comment: @DavidManners a legible answer.

Comment: Can you force the "Save in Address List" option to appear even if you select an existing address?  Is the behavior the same if this is not checked while selecting an existing address?  If not, my guess is that the default behavior when that option is not available is to always save.

Comment: @Tim would be interesting to find out if this has always been the case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usualy, unless data has changed on a model, calling save() on it **will not cause the model to be re-saved**.
This must have been the assumption during implementing the logic this way.

However, since the quote address model's method `_beforeSave()` sets the quote ID, the customer ID, plus possibly the customer address ID and the `same_as_billing` property via the `_populateBeforeSaveData()` method, the protection against unnecessary saving is circumvented.

An easy fix in the method `populateBeforeSaveData()` would be to check if the values about to be set on the address model already present on the current model with the same value.

Fortunately, quote addresses are stored in a flat table, which means the save is fairly efficient. And except for some B2B stores I haven't experienced customers having more then a couple of addresses.

Answer (score 2):

I would hazard a guess that this was not thought through.

Maybe it was thought that rather than updating any new address plus any change in default billing and shipping address it would be easier just to save everything, since people wont have that many addresses and the checkout is already slow people wont notice....much.

**Note: this is just an idea but I thought it worth sharing, also I can imagine myself making the same assumptions :(**

Answer (score 0):

address save during checkout is done by _afterSave()-Method in customer resource model.

```
protected function _afterSave(Varien_Object $customer)
{
    $this->_saveAddresses($customer);
    return parent::_afterSave($customer);
}
```

as i remember customer model get saved during order placement.

cheers

Comment: Yes, that was clear. The question is "What for?".

Comment: @Tim: general i think. No observably reason for checkout atm.

Comment: @Tim: For example saveAction in admin needs this behavior.

Comment: What for does it need it?